# python ping get error:Operation not permitted - Note that ICMP messages can only be send from processes running as root

Tags: python, root, ping, privileges

When using pyping to ping to a host under linux,I got this error:

```
Operation not permitted - Note that ICMP messages can only be send from processes running as root.
```

Any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to run it with `sudo`?

Comment: @Sraw,thx,sudo will work,but it shouldn't do

Comment: You cannot create an ICMP packet without root privileges as it needs a raw socket which is only allowed to be created by root user. This is not a limitation of module but system.

Comment: BTW, You may argue that "Oh I have ran ping with normal user millions of times". Try `ls -l /bin/ping`, you will see `-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root`, that means `ping` has `SetUID`. More information about `SetUID`, you can google it. In short, `SetUID` gives normal user root privileges when executing `ping`.

Comment: Thanks very much,I didn't express it clearly that I knew it must,but I don't want to run it as root,so I wander that if any possible to avoid it